Issue for deploying app on VPS with Docker
I'm trying to deploy my app on VPS :
When I execute the command
docker compose -f docker-compose.production.yml --env-file .env.production up --build
I have an error message :
server-1  | > pronos_server@0.0.1 start:prod
server-1  | > node build/index.js
server-1  |
server-1  | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
server-1  |   throw err;
server-1  |   ^
server-1  |
server-1  | Error: Cannot find module '/app/build/index.js'
server-1  |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
server-1  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
server-1  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
server-1  |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
server-1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
server-1  |   requireStack: []
server-1  | }
server-1  |
server-1  | Node.js v20.12.2

It tries to start from app/build/index.js but when it builds the app I specified app/build/src/index.js.
Here is my Dockerfile.production :
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add curl
RUN apk add make g++ python3 git
RUN npm i -g node-pre-gyp

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i -g

COPY .env ./.env
COPY src ./src
COPY tsconfig.json ./

RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]

CMD ["npm","run","start:prod"]

And this is my scrip in package.json :
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start:prod": "node build/src/index.js",
    "seed": "ts-node-dev seed.ts"
  },

When I build locally this is the result :
Build in my IDE
Thanks a lot if anyone has a clue or can help.
Docker can't file the index.js file in the build file. Try to change the script in package.json to :
    "start:prod": "node build/index.js", but same issue.
I also noticed that the build is working with git hub actions :

Here is the related github workflow :
name: Compile and push client and server to production

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-push-server:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          push: true
          context: "{{defaultContext}}:server"
          file: "Dockerfile.production"
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/pronos-des-potos_server
  build-and-push-client:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          push: true
          context: "{{defaultContext}}:client"
          file: "Dockerfile.production"
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/pronos-des-potos_client

...
